# static_assert with SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

The standard says in [temp.res]/8:

> No diagnostic shall be issued for a template definition for which a valid specialization can be generated. If no valid specialization can be generated for a template definition, and that template is not instantiated, the template definition is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. ... [ Note: If a template is instantiated, errors will be diagnosed according to the other rules in this Standard. Exactly when these errors are diagnosed is a quality of implementation issue. — end note ]

My question is: Does the following count as a valid specialization that can be generated?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class A;

template <typename T>
class A<T, typename std::enable_if<not std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type>
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "should not be here!");
};
```

On the one hand, the `static_assert` essentially amounts to a `static_assert(false, "should not be here");` (we can't both not be an `int` and be an `int` at the same time), which isn't allowed. On the other hand, as far as SFINAE is concerned, the type, e.g., `A<double>` is perfectly well formed and can be generated, but will immediately throw a static assertion failure. This currently works in GCC 8.3, but given the "ill-formed, no diagnostic required" part of the standards quote above, I want to make sure that it actually ***should*** work. (Note: work here is defined to mean it throws a `static assertion` failed if I try to instantiate a `A<double>` and compiles silently if I don't)

Comment: I'm confused. What works? What definition of "works" are we talking about?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Added a parenthetical to hopefully clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not *meant* to work. That is not a valid C++ program.

Per the very paragraph you cite, the template definition of your partial specialization is ill-formed NDR. There is no valid specialization that may be generated from it.

The standard typically designates something as ill-formed NDR because checking it reliably in the general case would amount to contradicting [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). So compilers aren't obligated to try, but they *may* try some heuristic analysis or other.

GCC and Clang often diagnose more as heuristics are added to them. I wouldn't try to claim "this is dependent" as a shield against that. The code itself is invalid from the get-go.

Comment: I guess I may have been confused as to what was meant by "generating" a valid specialization - if it was just enough to pass SFINAE, or if it meant there was actually a valid type that could be allowed to be instantiated. Your answer (as well as your comment on the answer above that some compilers reject `sizeof(T) == 0`) appear to indicate that it is the former, and not the latter.

Comment: @user11923373 - The normative text refers to a *template-definition* intentionally. I.e, the blueprint of the actual class we are generating. The spirit of [temp.res]/8  is about guarding against blueprints that cannot ever produce something valid. The SFINAE is a bit of a red herring. Because when it fails, we don't get a valid specialization from *that* template definition. And when it passes, we still get something invalid.